# Generate Create Table Query Dynamically For Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make an app that can store data but the schema of the data is given by the user. So somehow I need to pass the table name and columns' name to DatabaseHelper.java so use them in onCreate method.

I found out you can pass strings using Intent but here it didn't work because it turned out it works only between activites.

So I can get the information from the user and but it in a string separating names with commas. But I can't send the string to DatabaseHelper.java to execute in onCreate.

[image: How I get Info]

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to use another approach? Or is this something impossible?

Thanks in advance, all
Best

My method to get the information and process it:

```
/* Called when the user clicks the Finalize button */
    public void createSchema(View view) {
        String create_table = ""; // Store table name and columns name
        schemaName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.create_schema_name);
        String schemaNameString = schemaName.getText().toString().trim();
        fieldsContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fieldsContainer);
        int childCount = fieldsContainer.getChildCount();
        if (schemaNameString.length() != 0) {
            // When the name is entered
            if (childCount > 0) {
                // When there is at least one field entered
                create_table += this.slug(schemaNameString) + ",_id,timestamp,latitude,longitude,";
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    View childView = fieldsContainer.getChildAt(i);
                    TextView childTextView = (TextView)(childView.findViewById(R.id.added_schema_field));
                    String childTextViewString = childTextView.getText().toString();
                    create_table += this.slug(childTextViewString) + ",";
                }
                create_table = create_table.substring(0, create_table.length() - 1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), create_table, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Doesn't work
                // Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseHelper.java);
                // intent.putExtra(CREATE_TABLE, create_table);
                // startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // No field entered
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There must be at least one field entered to " + schemaNameString + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }           
        } else {
            // No name entered
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No name entered for the schema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

My DatabaseHelper.java:

```
package com.example.draft;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";

    // Doesn't work
    // Intent intent = getIntent();
    // String create_table = intent.getStringExtra(CreateSchemaActivity.CREATE_TABLE);

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You will need to manage your database, and its upgrades, yourself, working directly with `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Thank you! I did that and it's working now. I'm not sure if this is safe though. :/ SQL commands are executed directly in a method in the corresponding activity using try, catch and finally.